# Secure access to ESXi guests from outside of my home network

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

I have an HP Proliant DL380 G4 running ESXi 4.1. So far, I have Server 2008 and Linux Mint guests running on the host. What I want to do is access either of these VM's from outside of my home (i.e. free wireless hotspots). Would OpenVPN and some sort of RDP/VNC software help me accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a secured VPN for that, may be Citrix, Fortinet etc. You need to configure public access to your virtual machines through a VPN software, and then, once you have the necessary VPN client installed on your machine, you can access it remotely. OpenVPN also has such a solution but need to be explored, if that fits your requirement.